# Hibernate/JPA one-to-many relationship if parent reference is defined as an ID with no parent reference

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

Standard way to define one-to-many relationship in Hibernate/JPA is to have a reference in a Child object to its Parent object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Child> children;

    // ... 
}



@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    // ... 
}
```

The problem with this method is that Child becomes a heavyweight class, which is harder to send across the wire, etc.

Is it possible to define a one-to-many relationship with no Parent object referenced from Child and with no additional reference/join table? In that case Child class defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    // ...

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: Sure, but why are you incurring all the overhead of ORM if you don't actually want to use ORM?

Comment: Both Parent and Child are complex objects and I'd like the power of ORM to help me read and write them, but once a Parent is read I'd like to be able to use its children as independent entities without the need to carry Parent around.

Comment: No, you can't do it ORM used to compose a referential integrity between two objects, so you keep it less informant.

Comment: nikpon, please remove your edits. Those names were capitalized on purpose as they are class names. As far as your answer, it's not clear what you were trying to say. It's up to a developer how to maintain integrity.

Comment: You shouldn't design entities based on what must be sent over the wire. You should design them based on what the data model is. Then annotate, adapt or transform your entity when you want to send it over the wire. If using Jackson to transform it to JSON, for example, you could add a getParentId() getter, and annotate the parent field with @JsonIgnore, and the parent ID would be sent over the wire instead of the whole parent object.

Comment: JB, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but Hibernate expects me to define Parent member not just integer id to it. You can avoid it by using a join table, but that creates unnecessary database complexity and potential performance impact.

Comment: And you should follow Hibernate's best practices. A Child has a parent, not an ID of a parent. This association is natural, and extremely useful to have in all the business logic and HQL queries. That's one of the reasons for using ORMs in the first place. Adapt the serialization logic instead of corrupting the object model.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `JPA 2.0`, it is possible `OneToMany` uni-direction with no parent entity at child entity.

Parent.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Set<Child> children;
}
```

Child.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {
    // No need to hold parent entity
    //@ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    //private Parent parent;
}
```

[More Reference](http://webdev.apl.jhu.edu/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/605-784-site/docs/content/html/jpa-relationex-one2many-uni.html)

Comment: There's a problem with your definition. When you add a Child to a Parent and then try saving the Parent you get something like cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."CHILD"."PARENT_ID"). This means that Hibernate is unable to save the graph. Not sure if it can read it because I need to save at least one instance before I can read.